# What is wrong with the following findstr batch code?

Tags: windows, batch

I want to create a batch file that will scan for a string in every file in the directory I assign, including going through the sub-directories automatically. Here is what I wrote, and it does not seem to work:

```
@echo off 

goto findstring

:stringnotfound

echo %string% not found in %location%

pause >nul

:findstring

set /p string=string:

set /p location=location:

findstr /i /p /m /s "%string%" %location%

if %errorlevel% == 1 goto stringnotfound
```

What am I missing out on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your problem. the FINDSTR method looks for a file as a location. I can't see what parameters your are using but I'm assuming you're not inputing a file name at the end of your location. You have to use wildcards if you want to look in multiple files. Here is an example of you script that I modified that seems to work just fine:

```
@echo off 
goto findstring

:stringnotfound

echo %string% not found in %location%

pause >nul

:findstring

set /p string=string:

set location=C:\test\*.* 

findstr /i /p /m /s %string% %location% 

if %errorlevel% == 1 goto stringnotfound
```

Note that I'm not inputting the location through the prompt so that you can see the difference. I'm using the wildcard to search in all the files.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, works :) I was confused, because I thought * . * because it has a dot, would only look through any files with any extensions in the directory, and not look through the sub directories. Apparently what you wrote works, I only had to make it so the user can specify the location instead of being set (which I did by adding \ * . * to the end of %location% in the findstr line)

Comment: Great, glad I could help!